# C++ - Problema com codigo

Tags: c++

a maioria das variáveis ​​funciona, mas "guess" aparentemente deve ser modificável e tem muitos argumentos em sua chamada de função. Como faço para corrigir isso?

```cpp
//header
#pragma once
class Game
{
public:
 Game();
 void reset();
 void run();
 int secretnum = rand() % 100 + 1;
 int guesscount = 5;
 int guess;
 int n;
 const int MAX_SECRET = 100;
 int Game::getNumber() {
  int guess;
  std::cin >> guess;
  while (std::cin.fail()) {
   std::cin.clear();
   std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
   std::cout << "Please enter a valid number: ";
   std::cin >> guess;
 }
private:

private:
 int  secretNumber;
};
```

```cpp
//game.ccp
//initialize variables
#include "Game.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
//game
const int MAX_SECRET = 100;
Game::Game()
{
 srand(time(0));
}
void Game::reset()
{
 const int secretnum = rand() % MAX_SECRET + 1;
}
void Game::run()
{
 reset();
 std::cout << "secret number is: " << secretnum 
  << "\nTODO create game\n\n";
 int secretnum = rand() % 100 + 1;
 int guesscount = 5;
 int guess;
 char playGame;
 std::cout << "Guess a number between 1 and 100. " << "\n";
 std::cin >> guess;
 getNumber(guess);
 if (guess > 100 || guess < 1)
 {
  std::cout << "Guess must be between 1 and 100. " << "\n";
  std::cin >> guess;
 }
 else if (guess < secretnum && guesscount > 0)
 {
  guess = guess - 1;
  std::cout << "Higher. " << "\n";
  std::cout << "You have " << guesscount << " guess(es) left." << "\n";
  std::cin >> guess;
 }
 else if (guess > secretnum && guesscount > 0)
 {
  guess = guess - 1;
  std::cout << "Lower. " << "\n";
  std::cout << "You have " << guesscount << " guess(es) left." << "\n";
  std::cin >> guess;
 }
 else if (guess != secretnum && guesscount = 1)
 {
  std::cout << "GAME OVER " << "\n";
  playGame = false;
 }
 else if (guess = secretnum)
 {
  std::cout << "That's correct! Well done! " << "\n";
  playGame = false;
 }
}
int Game::getNumber() {
 int guess;
 std::cin >> guess;
 while (std::cin.fail()) {
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n');
  std::cout << "Please enter a valid number: ";
  std::cin >> guess;
 }
 return guess;
}
```

```cpp
//source.ccp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Game.h"
//main loop
int main() {
 Game game;

 std::cout << "Guess a number between 1 - 100\n" <<
  "Would you like to play (y/n): ";

 char playGame;
 std::cin >> playGame;
 while ('Y' == toupper(playGame))
 {
  game.run();
  std::cout << "play again (y/n): ";
  std::cin >> playGame;
  system("CLS");
 }
}
```

Comment: Pelo que pude observar a variável `guess`, declarada em mais de uma função, é uma variável `int` e não uma função.

Answer (score 0):

Você está criando uma classe contendo a variável `guess`. O problema é que dentro dos métodos da classe você declara uma **outra variável** local com o mesmo nome. Ou seja, se mudar o valor de `guess` nesse método você vai mudar a variável local (que será destruída ao sair da função) e não o atributo da classe. Remova `int guess;` de dentro dos métodos.